# TeamCity SVN authentication error

Tags: svn, teamcity

I am using TeamCity (8.0.3 on Win XP) to simply execute a VBS script file in a DOS command shell. The script interacts with SVN to export various files from various repositories and places them to a location on the local machine.

When I run this script "manually" in a DOS command shell (i.e. outside and independent of TeamCity), the script executes successfully without issues. In terms of interaction with SVN, the script simply executes the `svn export` command and I do not supply `--username` or `--password`. Should credentials be required, then SVN will force me to enter those in order for the script to continue within the DOS window, which it does. Obviously, after this Windows will cache the credentials so that the next time I choose to run this script, it just works as I assume it already knows the credentials.

Now, given that the TeamCity Server AND TeamCity Agent are on the SAME machine as when I ran the script manually, this same script does not work when TeamCity executes it.

In particular, then script hangs as soon as it attempts to execute the `svn export` command

```
svn export -r HEAD "PATH_TO_FILE_IN_SVN_REPO" "PATH_TO_FILE_ON_LOCAL_MACHINE"
```

I have tried to add `--non-interactive` to my `SVN export` command in my script but that just gives me

> svn: OPTIONS of '[subversion-url]': authorization failed: Could not
>   authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge
>   (http://[subversion-host])

From my investigations, I think that the script is executed by TeamCity using another user called "Default User" which lives under 'C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\" and when I attempt to run the script manually under this user, then the script hangs and when I press `Ctrl+C`, I can see that the script was waiting from MY user accounts AD password.

I've tried to force TeamCity to use my local cached Windows credentials, but to no avail.

Please help!! I'm out of ideas here :|

Thanks in advance.